# Output £ as PowerShell String

Tags: powershell

I run the following to populate with data from a CSV file:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\RGETH\Downloads\suppliercontracttemplate.csv

foreach ($row in $csv) {
   Add-HbSpmSupplierContract -supplierId $row.supplierContractId -name $row.supplier -description $row.description -type $row.type -startDate $row.startDate -endDate $row.endDate -currency $row.currency -value $row.value -cancellationNoticePeriod $row.cancellationNoticePeriod -costCentre $row.costCentre -invoiceNumber $row.invoiceNumber -orderNumber $row.orderNumber -paymentType $row.paymentType -status $row.status -ownedBy $row.ownedBy -budgetOwner $row.budgetOwner -notes $row.notes -custom0 $row.custom0 -custom1 $row.custom1 -custom2 $row.custom2
```

I need to populate `-currency $row.currency with a £ symbol, I have tried escaping with a backtick, but the currency field fails to populate as a string.

[image: Example CSV]

Comment: Have you tried converting the `£` to an entity `&#163;` or as hex `&#xA3;` or as named entity `&pound;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment. That function seems to create XML tags and the pound symbol should then be entered as **entity** like in decimal form `&#163;` or as hex `&#xA3;`

You can hardcode that of course, but I would use

```
# put this at the top of your script somewhere
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

# guessing that the 'currency' field in your CSV contains the string "£", convert it to entity like this
Add-HbSpmSupplierContract ... -currency ([System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($row.currency))
```

If you're using a PowerShell version => 3.0 (.Net 4.0) you can use the `[System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode()` method and you don't have to add an assembly first:

```
Add-HbSpmSupplierContract ... -currency ([System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode($row.currency))
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a wild guess and assuming you want to *translate* a three letter currency code to the according symbol you could use a hashtable ... like this:

```
$Currency = @{
    GBP = '£'
    EUR = '€'
    USD = '$'
    YEN = '¥'
}

$CSVInput = 'GBP'

$Currency[$CSVInput]
```

Adapted to your function call this should work then:

```
$Currency[$($row.currency)]
```